# Mimic Wordpress Permalink Structure in a React Application

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React to build the front-end of a site that uses Wordpress as a back-end. My goal is to mimic the most simple permalink structure in Worpdress, that is the site domain + the slug of the page or posts, without the addition of any `/posts/` or `/news/` or whatever. In other words, something like `http://example.com/hello-world/`for posts and `http://example.com/about/` for pages.

I'm very new to React and I'm having some trouble understanding how to do that with React Router.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import MainHeader from './components/main-header/MainHeader';
import SinglePost from './pages/SinglePost';

const Layout = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <MainHeader />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />
                <Route exact path="/:slug" render={ props => <SinglePost { ...props } /> } />
                <Route render={ () => { return( <p>Not Found</p> ) } } />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Layout;
```

This works fine for loading single posts with the permalink structure I've mentioned above, e.g. `http://example.com/hello-world`. The problem is, when I try to reach a page such as `http://example.com/about`, `path="/:slug"`is also matched, which means that the `SinglePost` component will be used for pages as well, while I want to use a different one.

How can I use different components for single posts and pages, while keeping the same permalink structure?

By the way, below is how I render my list of posts, with links to each individual post. Should I perhaps edit `Link` in some way?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ListPosts = ( props ) => {

    let postsList = props.posts.map( ( post, index ) => {
        return( 
            <article key={ index }>
                <h2><Link to={ post.slug }>{ post.title.rendered }</Link></h2>
            </article>
        )
    });

    return (
        <section className="posts">
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            { postsList }
        </section>
    );

}

export default ListPosts;
```